# Recommended file system setup for development projects?

Tags: macos, filesystems, development-environment, environment, developer-tools

I just got a new computer (Mac, if relevant) and I'm in the process of downloading IDEs and other stuff intended for development. **Is there a recommended pattern for setting up the file system for development?**

On a different computer in the past, I just created a folder titled `Development` in the home directory and then all workspaces were dumped in there. There is a `workspace` folder for Eclipse projects and then some other folders for Xcode projects.

I searched and read [this blog post](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/mac-setup/) that recommends [the conventions for Go](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Overview). Any other recommended setups?

I plan to contribute to open source projects and to have some Xcode and Java projects of my own, if any of that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be primarily opinion based, but the folder structure I've settled on is based on my use cases. I generally have two ways I use code: experimenting with a language, and working on a project (and that project sometimes has multiple languages). Accordingly, I create two folder heirarchies: `~/Code/<language>/` for experimenting with a language, and `~/Git/<projectname>/` for projects.

The `Code` might look something like this:

```
Code/
├── Bash
│   └── tmp.sh
├── C
│   └── tmp.c
├── CPP
│   └── tmp.cpp
└── Python
    ├── multifile
    │   ├── first.py
    │   └── second.py
    └── tmp.py
```

And the Git folder would look something like this:

```
Git/
├── CoolProject
└── Project1
    ├── README.md
    ├── doc
    └── src
```

In the `Code` directory, I worry much less about structure or documentation. Once/If a project grows big or important enough to version control I place it in the `Git` directory where I try to follow the conventional folder hierarchy for the language, like your Go link, or this [Python guide](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/) or whatever Eclipse would make for Java. I do try to have a README.md at the root level of each project so I'll know what it does and I can put it on GitHub easily.